# How do I escape values in Splunk?

Tags: escaping, special-characters, splunk

Splunk best practices say to use key/value pairs.  It also says to wrap values in quotes if they contain spaces.  So, let's say I have a raw value of `Fred Smith`:

```
my_key=name my_value="Fred Smith"
```

That's fine, I've added the quotes.  But what if I have a raw value of `" Fred Smith"` (note the quotes already present and the presence of a space at the start) - this would yield:

```
my_key=name my_value="" Fred Smith""
```

This would be treated as:

```
my_key=name my_value=""
my_key=Fred my_value=Smith""
```

What are the best practices for escaping quotes in Splunk values?

Comment: Have you tried using a backslash on the quote? That seems to work for me in the search field.

Answer (score 9):

If you control the data format, which it appears you do, your options include:

- Add single quotes around everything.
- Use double-quotes, but escape the inner ones with backslashes
- Use JSON to represent the data instead of a flat string of KV pairs. JSON syntax handles this quoting case (without adding extra quote marks), plus you can add nested structure if you want.

You can control the search-time field extraction behavior by setting `KV_MODE`. You may find that `auto_escaped` will do the trick. See [Setting KV_MODE for search-time data](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.4/Knowledge/Createandmaintainsearch-timefieldextractionsthroughconfigurationfiles#Setting_KV_MODE_for_search-time_data) in the Splunk Knowledge Manager manual.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"my_value=\"Fred Smith"`. Key and value between double quotes but the intern double quote with escape `\"`.